# how to get youtube video title using URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have youtube video URLs saved in the database and i am embedding them in my webpage using iframe, is there a way to get video titles using c# code without using any APIs.

Comment: Then use one - YouTube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: OP asks to get the title **without** APIs. A simple web get and then some HTML parsing will suffice.

Comment: I think the OP means "without code in a DLL" or "without an SDK".  The word "API" is generally used on the web to refer to service endpoints, which the OP will definitely be using to solve this problem. Semantics - maybe clarify in original question.

Comment: Querying the YouTube data API is a lot easier than doing an HTML get and some parsing. And a lot more reliable, as you'll find out the first time they change their HTML and all of a sudden your scraping code doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 10):

If you dont want to use the API directly, you can use this small function I wrote a long time ago.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;

public static void Main()
{
    var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHfWY0is3rE";
    string name = GetTitle(url);
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}

public static string GetTitle(string url)
{
    var api = $"http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={GetArgs(url, "v", '?')}";
    return GetArgs(new WebClient().DownloadString(api), "title", '&');
}

private static string GetArgs(string args, string key, char query)
{
    var iqs = args.IndexOf(query);
    return iqs == -1
        ? string.Empty
        : HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(iqs < args.Length - 1
            ? args.Substring(iqs + 1) : string.Empty)[key];
}
```

But you really should use the API instead of this. Basically I use (a tiny part of) the API. Keep in mind that if YouTube updates their API, this code may not work. Follow the official API's documentation for more informations.

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QggRh0)

Comment: Not familiar with this class "Address" - is that a custom class you created?

Comment: @RickDailey In fact, you dont need it here. I removed it and I added a normal WebClient.

Comment: @aloisdg for me, your code returns the title as "streaming-media" no matter what the video id.

Comment: @DarshanMiskin I tried. It works. [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QggRh0)

Comment: @aloisdg thanks for the help, i resolved the issue a few days later when i posted that comment. :)

Comment: @DarshanMiskin Glad to hear it :)

Comment: how to do it with description? i changed `title` to `description` but it didn't work

Comment: @newbieguy I think it should be a new question. :)

Comment: @aloisdg Yeah, though i already got it without using youtube api